# Visual studio code Python execution

Tags: python-3.x, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-sdk-python

I seem to have some path issue while running Python(v3.9.1) in Visual studio code .The Azure libraries/SDK are not picked up while running the python file.
Do I need to set the Azure SDK in the Python path ?

```
 from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igX7S.gif

Comment: You don't need to set the Azure SDK in the Python path.

Comment: Reinstall python on your machine, and  `Ctrl+ Shift +p` in vscode -> `Python: Select  Interpreter` -> `Enter Interpreter Path` -> `Find`.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not needed. But for every project, it is recommended that you always create and activate a [python virtual environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-local-development-environment?tabs=cmd#use-python-virtual-environments) using:

```
# This command runs the Python venv module and creates a virtual environment in a folder named .venv.
py -3 -m venv .venv

# Activate the virtual environment
.venv\scripts\activate
```

A virtual environment is a folder within a project that isolates a copy of a specific Python interpreter. Once you activate that environment (which Visual Studio Code does automatically), running `pip install` installs a library into that environment only.

When you then run your Python code, it runs in the environment's exact context with specific versions of every library. You can create a `requirements.txt` file for the libraries you need, then use `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Here is a snippet from a sample requirements.txt file:

```
azure-cli-core==2.11.1
azure-cli-telemetry==1.0.6
azure-common==1.1.25
azure-core==1.8.1
azure-identity==1.4.0
azure-mgmt-compute==17.0.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.2.0
azure-mgmt-network==16.0.0
azure-mgmt-resource==10.2.0
```

If you don't use a virtual environment, then Python runs in its **global** environment that is shared by any number of projects.

Refer to the [Azure SDK for Python Developer docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-local-development-environment?tabs=cmd) for more information on configuring your local Python dev environment for Azure.